# Sticky element in adminlte

Tags: html, css, laravel, adminlte

Currently I'm working with adminlte template, and I want to make an element with sticky behavior, but I don't know it seems I can't do it even placing in diverent div's.

I want to place the sticky div under the navbar(in this orange div):
[image: i want to place the sticky div under the navbar(in this orange div)]

CSS:

```
.sticky{
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  width: 100%;
}
```

HTML:

```
@section('content')
<div id="page-top" style="margin-top: -15px ">
<div class="sticky" style="background: #66c1bd;height: 3em;top:0px;position: sticky;position: -webkit-sticky;">
        test
      </div>
  <!-- multistep form -->
  <!-- The Modal -->
</div>
```

Even I use inline CSS still not working,

The preview

beginning:
[image: beginning]

after scroll a bit:
[image: after scroll a bit]

Another info, I'm using laravel. But don't think it is the problem.

Comment: What is your current output like?

Comment: currently my output is same like i put div on regular div, it keep scrolling with it.

Comment: The behavior you get is intended for "sticky elements". 
They are placed according the html structure, but they only
scroll up to a given top value.

What You might want is a fixed element. Fixed elements will not scroll

Comment: i try,but the fixed element doesn't fits my need, because it'll leave a gap after i scroll ( the navbar scroll  up but the div still have top:3em; gap)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I've found the right answer to my question.

The `position:sticky` can't work well in adminLTE because of the `<div class="wrapper">` (you can found it under body tag.

I inspired from this [article](http://dinbror.dk/blog/help-css-position-sticky-doesnt-work-solved/)., It mention that the sticky won't work if we put it under parent that has `overflow:hidden` so the browser can't calculate the correct value (height) to determine when it to be sticky

So the conclusion

> make sure the `overflow` of your parent div set to be `style="overflow:visible visible;"` to overide the style that adminLTE has.

This is the full syntax of mine:

```
<body class="hold-transition skin-black-light sidebar-mini">
<!-- Site wrapper --><div class="wrapper" style="overflow:visible visible;">
```

Answer (score -1):

Maby if you make it not sticky but

```
.sticky {
   position: fixed;
}
```

Comment: Consider formatting your answer so your example is within blocks, similar to how it was originally asked.

Comment: hello,
i have put the top:0px; before, and it not make any change.
and to make sure, i put it back and again, it give nothing.